# Open interactive telnet session from Python

Tags: python, telnet

I am currently writing a small script in Python which reads some possible connections from a database (triple of node name, telnet IP address and telnet port) and present that to the user to choose to which node to connect.

After this selection I want to open an interactive Telnet session, which can be used by the user as if he had manually connected using the telnet command. Somehow I probably will need an escape sequence for that. It only needs to work on Linux OS.

I could just call telnet:

```
# Open shell
call(["telnet", selected_node['ip'], selected_node['port']])
```

That does work. However, I wonder if there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's python, everything is included. There is a `telnet` [module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/telnetlib.html) in the standard library.

```
import getpass
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until(b"login: ")
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

tn.write(b"ls\n")
tn.write(b"exit\n")

print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. How does that fit in with the requirement having an *interactive* telnet session the user can use as if he has opened the telnet connection himself?

Comment: Sounds like your script needs to read user input, send it to the telnet instance, read the output and show it to the user in a loop.

Comment: Then I'll probably stick with just opening telnet as an external program, that actually works quite well. Was just wondering if there would be a better / more pythonic way without re-inventing the wheel. Thanks for your answer though.